# tvOS 16.0 can't click "MENU" to pop in the SSO login page, any ideas?, thanks

Tags: single-sign-on, tvos

[image]

```
VSAccountManager.enqueue(request) { (userMetadata, vsaError) in
// to do
// can't callback
}
```

tvOS 16.0: click "MENU" on Remote, nothing happend?!
tvOS 15.* or before: click "MENU" on Remote, will callback with "Cancel" action.

Answer (score 0):

In the tvOS 16.0, need to focus on the "Continue" button manual, then click "MENU" to activate the "Cancel" action.

(type in any words to activate the "Continue" button below